# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined : redux-reactstrap-modal

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm Using [redux-reactstrap-modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgZW2.png) for my project.
When i configure webpack and babel,i'm getting bellow error on web page.

[image]

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies":{
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "redux-reactstrap-modal": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
}
```

Playmodel.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import reduxDialog, { closeDialog, openDialog } from 'redux-reactstrap-modal';
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
    import { compose } from 'recompose';

    class PlayModal extends Component {

     render() {
            const { data, t } = this.props;
            return (
                <div>
                 ............
                </div>);

       }
    }


    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators({ closeDialog, openDialog }, dispatch);
    }

export default (reduxDialog({ name: 'MODAL_PLAY',backdrop:'static'}), connect(null, mapDispatchToProps))(PlayModal);
```

Comment: Some code can be useful

Comment: This is the only change what i did.just installed babel and webpack.then application show me that error

Comment: You propably need to give the modal a prop `name` which is required. do that for all the modals extended from this package. [from](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-reactstrap-modal#modal-props), starting from `PlayWith` component.

Comment: @SultanH. it's also given `export default (reduxDialog({ name: 'MODAL_OTP',backdrop:'static'}), 
connect(null, mapDispatchToProps))(OTPModal);`   . and app was run without any error before install webpack

Comment: Can you show include the code for the export statement in the answer well-formatted and as it is in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you consider this as a replacement to `PlayModal` Component, updates where made to export statement of the Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import reduxDialog, { closeDialog, openDialog } from 'redux-reactstrap-modal';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { compose } from 'recompose';

class PlayModal extends Component {

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {
         /** SOME JSX */
       }
     </div>
   )
 }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ closeDialog, openDialog }, dispatch);
}

const WithDialog = reduxDialog(connect, { name: 'MODAL_PLAY',backdrop:'static'})(PlayModal);
const ConnectedWithDialog = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WithDialog);

export default ConnectedWithDialog;
```

Comment: I have updated `WithDialog` declaration in the answer, as reading [from](https://github.com/anis-campos/redux-reactstrap-modal/blob/d71754dc075e41f92021c579462d00784c580d9d/examples/index.js#L35), `reduxDialog` needed `connect` as the first param, the current declaration causes the second param which is `settings` to be undfined, can we try this?

Comment: Great! was it as I described or did you find another solution?